# Visualforce Remoting Correct Approach?

Tags: visualforce, javascript, bestpractice, remote-action

I have a controller with the below (sanitized) methods:

```
@remoteAction
global static String getParam1(String someInput1){
    String param1 = someInput1;
    return param1;
}

@remoteAction
global static String getParam2(String someInput2){
    String param2 = someInput2;
    return param2;
}
```

And a VF page with the following javascript:

```
<script>

//vf remoting
Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction("{!$RemoteAction.controller.getParam1}", aninputhere, function(result,event){
var jsParam1 = result;});

//calling method directly
controller.getParam2(aninputhere,function(result,event){
    var jsParam2 = result;});

</script>
```

While I have done this inconsistently by accidental both work fine in all contexts that they are used...is there any benefit/reason I should use the vf remoting approach in javascript over calling the controller directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just verbosity. I prefer the latter because it is more concise. As far as I know, that's the only difference. As a direct consequence, it is also somewhat easier to pass the reference to a static resource/angular framework/etc, since you can pass a single function instead of the entire manager.

As a simple example, you could add that specific function to a namespace:

```
(function (w) {
    "use strict";
    w.myNamespace = w.myNamespace || {};
    w.myNamespace.callRemoteAction = controller.getParam2;
    // other logic, cleanup, etc.
}(window));
```

Comment: Makes sense and I did see reference to namespace in the docs: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_js_remoting_invoking.htm

Comment: @Girbot I'm using it in a different sense here. More like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881515/how-do-i-declare-a-namespace-in-javascript).

Comment: @AdrianLarson With namespaces the latter approach has created issues in the past .Is this fixed now ? Do you package your code ?

Comment: @MohithShrivastava Nope, I've never packaged anything. Interesting. It seems like you should be able to work around that limitation, but I'll trust you that for managed code it's simpler to `invokeAction`. I still hold that it's easier to incorporate the above into SPA architecture though.

Comment: You can pass the global variable {!$RemoteAction.controller.getParam1} and use Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(windowvariable) in the SPA .

Answer (score 2):

I will prefer the first approach of using $RemoteAction

```
Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction("{!$RemoteAction.controller.getParam1}", aninputhere, function(result,event){
```

The reason is this is namespace independent and I will not have to worry about namespace when i package the visualforce page for managed package application as the platform automatically takes care of namespacing  .